# Prove that there exists a subspace $X$ such that $W+X=V$ and $W\cap X=U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $W$ and $U$ are two subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $U$ is also a subspace of $W$, show that there exists a subspace $X$ of $V$ such that $W+X=V$ and $W\cap X=U$.

My attempt: I guess that $X = \langle U \cup W^\complement \rangle$ will work and also it is not difficult to show that $W+X=V$ will happen in this case, but I could not show that $W\cap X=U$ will also be true.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Isn't it necessary for $V$ to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: @schneiderlog: no. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a chain of three subspaces $U \subset W \subset V$ and you want a subspace $X$ of $V$ such that $W + X$ is $V$ and $W \cap X = U$. To find a suitable $X$, pick a basis $B_U$ for $U$, extend it to a basis $B_W$ for $W$ and then extend that to a basis $B_V$ for $V$. Then take $X$ to be the subspace of $V$ spanned by $B_U \cup (B_V \setminus B_W)$.

[As mentioned in the comments, using set operations on the subspaces wont work. If you work with bases for the subspaces, you can use set operations to get a basis for the subspace you are looking for.]

Comment: How do you show that $W \cap X \subset U$?

Comment: By looking at the expression of an element of $W \cap X$ as a linear combination of elements of the basis $B_V$. The coefficients of basis elements that are in $B_W$ but not in $B_U$ must be zero.

Comment: I still didn't understand why those coefficients must be zero?

Comment: Think about the linear independence property of basis elements.

Comment: great, Thank you.